# Visual C++: Plot 3D chart

Tags: .net, visual-c++, plot

I need a library/reference for Visual C++ to plot a 3D chart like this one:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgSxO.jpg)

I've read that I can do it using OpenGL, DirectX... But I would like to use something easier, I think that it could exists!

Thank you,

regards.

Pd.: I edit to say that I have a 3d data array and I want to plot it, so the result can be the 3D surface shown in the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about using 3D chart [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489205%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you are using .Net C# or VB, you can use [Chart Control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraChartsChartControltopic) from DevExpress

Comment: Thank you for yor response but, it's only to plot 2D graphs right? The first link teachs how to give a 3D appearance to chart's bars, but the data is related to a 2d table.

I've edited the main message pointing that I have a 3d data array and I have to plot it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [LightningChart](http://www.arction.com)  works also in C++ apps, as they have instructions in  [their users manual](http://arction.com/download/lightningchart_ultimate_manual.pdf) how to include it MFC app. It's there in the end of the document. C++/CLI language is pretty useful.

In the chart suite, there's plenty of different 3D and 2D charts made with DirectX. I'm using it in C# WPF.

Comment: Thank you for your response Giorn. Finally, I used qwtplot3d to do the job. It is a free "old" tool, but works very nice for the purpose I wanted to. If you are interested, you can find it in https://sourceforge.net/projects/qwtplot3d/ (note that works with Qt).